# I want to hide a image button when session is destroyed or user logs out

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide the image button while user logs out or there is no session created. ( in my code i want to hide `<div class=right icons>` )

this image `<img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">` button

```
<div class="rightIcons">
  <a href="upload.php">
    <img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">
  </a>
  <?php echo ButtonProvider::createUserProfileNavigationButton($con, $userLoggedInObj->getUsername()); ?>
</div>

</div>

<div id="sideNavContainer" style="display:none;">
  <?php
            $navigationProvider = new NavigationMenuProvider($con, $userLoggedInObj);
            echo $navigationProvider->create();
            ?>

</div>

<div id="mainSectionContainer">
  <div id="mainContentContainer">
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a conditional if-else block to create this only if there is a session. I'm not too sure about PHP syntax but the basic idea is to check the session in the conditional and show this block only if the session exists.

Comment: wrap that div inside `if(!isset($_SESSION['<some index what you created for login user>'])){}`

Comment: Just wrap the element in an `if`-statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_SESSION['user']!=""){ ?>// If User is logged in
    <div class="rightIcons">
        <a href="upload.php">
            <img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">
        </a>
        <?php echo ButtonProvider::createUserProfileNavigationButton($con, $userLoggedInObj->getUsername()); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

Second Solution is
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?> // If User is logged in

    <div class="rightIcons">
        <a href="upload.php">
            <img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">
        </a>
        <?php echo ButtonProvider::createUserProfileNavigationButton($con, $userLoggedInObj->getUsername()); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method checks if the variable exists, there is also a method called [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) that checks if the variable is empty.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  //use is set to check if $_SESSION['user'] exist
  if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
    //if user exist then show image button
    <div class="rightIcons">
        <a href="upload.php">
            <img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">
        </a>
        <?php echo ButtonProvider::createUserProfileNavigationButton($con, $userLoggedInObj->getUsername()); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```